# show a button pressed effect when default key is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I want my button to have a pressed and released effect(simulating a mouse press) when i press my default key(enter).

I have tried doing this

```
   private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(btnLogin, "Pressed", true);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(btnLogin, "Normal", true);
                btnLogin_Click(sender, e);

            }
        }
```

Cant get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make your button Property IsDefault=True

Answer (score 0):

Try the following
'

```
private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(btnLogin, "Pressed", true);
            this.Refresh();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(btnLogin, "Normal", true);
            this.Refresh();
            btnLogin_Click(sender, e);
        }
    }
```

'

Comment: what do i have to add to use  this.Refresh();AFAIK there is no Refresh() in WPF

Comment: What i wanted to put through is even though the state of your button is changing, it is not being painted. Refresh draws the controls on your screen for Windows Form Applications and hence i thought same would be the case here....